# Extend Estimation Board so cards have more attributes

Tags: rally

I'm new to the rally-app-builder and using the Custom App screen.  I want to use the core Estimation Board but add more attributes to each card such as Iteration and Schedule State.  I tried to place some code in the method for boardconfig, however I have been unsuccessful.  Below is a link to the code from github since its a lot of text.

https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/legacy/EstimationBoardApp.html

Line 186 is the cardboardconfig line.  I added 'cardConfig' in an attempt to add more attributes to the card, but it's not working.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
            var cardboardConfig = {
                types: [],
                attribute: "PlanEstimate",
                columns: columns,
                maxCardsPerColumn: 200,
                items: that._getItems,
                sortAscending: true,
                order: "Rank",
                enableRanking: false
                cardConfig: {
                fields: ['Iteration', 'ScheduleState']}


            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this updated version of the board?

https://github.com/RallyCommunity/EstimationBoard

It's also available in the in-product community app catalog if that's enabled in your subscription.

That app allows you to pick what fields you'd like on your cards without having to change any code.  The app you linked to is very old and hopefully will be replaced by the one I linked to above at some point...

Comment: AWESOME!  This is exactly what I was trying to modify on the old report!  Would love to know why I couldn't, but in the mean time, this solves my needs! Woot!

Comment: Cool, glad that works for you.  I bet we could have figured out the original problem, but it is built with ancient technology and it's dangerous to go alone...